# Dummy transaction to check if a system is up

Tags: sql-server-2008, system-monitoring

We want  to send a dummy transaction through our system (Application - DB) to ensure it is still up every minute. If the transaction fails we are alerted - Thereby knowing within a minute if there is something wrong with our System.

If it is sent every minute there will be as many dummy transactions in the DB at the end of day as real ones. Is it wise to run a cleanup job to get rid of these or just run a void transaction after each one.

Is there any common approach to this? Or any alternative methods. 
We are using SCOM to control the TX to the SQL SERVER 2008 DB.

Comment: 1 minute seems a little over zealous. What is your recovery time objective for the application?

Comment: Client does not accept any down time outside the SLA. Secondary site is about 3 months from completion.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm asking. What is the SLA? The RTO should be based on the SLA.

Comment: I would like to check the system is up every minute